# Adding name attribute to `User` in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, devise, custom-attributes

I'm trying to add a name attribute to the User model provided by Devise.  I added a "name" column to my database, and changed the sign up view so that it asks for the user's name:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <p><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

It lets me log in, but when I check the database after doing so, `name: nil`.  Do I have to add something to Devise's `User` controller or something?  Thanks!

Comment: Woludn't you also need to create a migration that adds "name" to the database table for User?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Rails 3

in your user model locate;

```
 attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
```

and add :name on the end

Comment: what about rails4? since there're no such attr_accessible thing

Comment: @namiheike Not sure what the answer for rails 4 is at the moment, but a quick fix would be to add gem 'protected_attributes' to your gemfile. Then you can use attr_accessible

Comment: For Rails 4.0 (and newer), with strong parameters, take a look at the **[Rails and Devise](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise)** example application from the RailsApps project.

Answer (score 13):

### Rails 5 (in fact devise 4)

Tested for: rails 5.1.0 (devise 4.2.1)

There is no need to work with devise controllers.

Just add the following to your `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if:  :devise_controller?


protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])

  end
```

`devise_parameter_sanitizer.for` no longer works with Rails 5 (to be more correct, it is not supported in devise 4, which is the expected devise version in a Rails 5 context): use `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit` to avoid `undefined method 'for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer` error

Answer (score 10):

> Add this code to application_controller.rb

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?



protected
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
end
```

Answer (score 6):

## For Rails 4

Use like this

```
protected
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
end
```

Add additional fields at the end.

Comment: Where could I add this? Do I have to create a user_controller?

Comment: ` app / controllers / application_controller.rb` Example: https://github.com/mistergiri/ExamAwesomeIdeas/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Add `:name` to `attr_accessible` in User Model

Answer (score 1):

Write this code inside the ApplicationController class...

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if:  :devise_controller?

      protected

      def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
```

Answer (score 0):

uncomment some of the generated code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private

   def sign_up_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:gender,:age,:password,:password_confirmation) if params[:user].present?
   end
```

Add this in the controller that extends devise's default registration controller