# show user's first_name with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise

How to show user's first_name in page like "Hello, current_user.first_name", my schema

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "first_name", default: "", null: false
    t.string "last_name", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

when i tried to do in my page `<span>Hello, <%= current_user.email %></span>` it's all ok, but whet i tried  `<span>Hello, <%= current_user.first_name %></span>` it's show nothing. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please share the basic details of the current user that you have stored.

Comment: @asda111sd if you know the `current_user`'s `id` then check at rails console `User.find(1).first_name.present?` here i have given `1` user id you can check it by current_user id

Comment: current_user.id works correctly

Comment: @asda111sd You are saying same thing works and also doesn't work at the end. Please correct it.

Comment: @asda111sd  no you did not get me i mean to say on rails console check User.find(current_user_id).first_name.present? if it returns true of false? and replace current_user_id with your current_user.id

Comment: `first_name` and `last_name` inserting properly when you inserted? check this first then try to login `current_user.first_name`

Comment: @asda111sd could you share your `create action` of users?

Comment: I'm quite sure you are not saving the first_name value to user (correctly). If you go to rails console and add the first_name attribute and save the user then I believe you will see the user's first_name in your browser too.

Comment: @asda111sd, Did you checked in your database that first_name is present or not?

Comment: Am i the only one to find both the statements exactly same `<span>Hello, <%= current_user.email %></span>` ?

Comment: @gabbar that give me console User.find(1).first_name.present?
  User Load (13.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => false

Comment: @asda111sd thats clearly mean that you ur user don't have first_name. so kindly review your signup follow where you are saving user information and check if first_name is being saved or not ?

Comment: @Gabbar that's from my registration view   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: false %>
  </div>

Comment: @Gabbar if it's important that i have not any users controller because devise have not generate it

Comment: @asda111sd if you are following devise signup page than devise by default provides only email and password field with signup page, so you need to add more fields like first_name, last_name with signup page to get first_name here. here you can generate devise signup page and add fields there like first_name, last_name and .. so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is in your schema, you have `t.string "first_name", default: "", null: false` which saves the empty string in your database, if you don't pass the first_name.I'm quite sure you are not saving the first_name value to user anyhow and it is by default set to "". When you try to access `<span> <%= "Hello, #{current_user.first_name}" %></span>` here it return empty string.Here user is present as if user is not present then it would have given error as `first_name for nil:NilClass`.

add this to your ApplicationController

```
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    permit_attrs(%i[first_name last_name])
  end

  def permit_attrs(attrs)
    %i[sign_up account_update].each do |action|
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(action, keys: attrs)
    end
  end
```

in your new.html.erb you have two first name field change one as below:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: false, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

to

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: false, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ok, I changet default value, but it continues to don't save fields(

Comment: is it giving any error?. also provisw the passed parram

Comment: please send the params send in creat action

Comment: i have not any users controller because rails have not generated it

Comment: i can give link to github if it can help

Comment: yes you can. but beter option would be if you follow  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085669/adding-name-attribute-to-user-in-devise.

Comment: the first link will let you learn how to add external field to devise gem and add it to data base. and let me know if your are still stuck with this error.

Comment: this link might also help you. it is the best one http://www.bogotobogo.com/RubyOnRails/RubyOnRails_Devise_Adding_User_Field_and_Customization_Update_Saved.php

Comment: can you check my github? https://github.com/kolasPowerImproved/testroram

Comment: @asda111sd check by making these changes it worked for me.

Comment: @asda111sd is there any other query.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are seeking to display user information, this is how I handle that.

**Display User Input Fields**

```
<p> Hello <%= @user.first_name %>
```

Now, if you want to be able to show user input information IF they have it.

**If User Filled Out Form**

```
<% if @user.first_name? %>
  <p>Hello, <%= @user.first_name %></p>
<% else %>
  <p>Hello Anonymous User</p>
<% end %>
```